# How to use class as parameter (for Realm, for Retrofit, etc.)?

Tags: java

This is standard realm query:

```
private void doQuery() {
    RealmResults<User> result = realm.where(User.class)
            .equalTo("name", "John")
            .or()
            .equalTo("name", "Peter")
            .findAll();
}
```

I would like to use this as function with parameter, meaning **User & User.class** wouldn´t not be hardcoded, it would be provided as parameter. Something like this, but this is wrong. Please advice how to do that.

**EDIT: It seems that problem with "User.class" is solved, but "User" remains.**

```
private void doQuery(Class<? extends RealmObject> realmClass) {
    RealmResults<realmObject> result = realm.where(realmClass)
            .equalTo("name", "John")
            .or()
            .equalTo("name", "Peter")
            .findAll();
}
```

**EDIT: When you give me minus, please be so kind and explain why.**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use generics to define the input, like so:

```
private <T extends RealmObject> RealmResults<T> doQuery(Class<T> realmClass) {
    RealmResults<T> results = realm.where(realmClass)
            .equalTo("name", "John")
            .or()
            .equalTo("name", "Peter")
            .findAll();
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, perfect!